# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (100, 2) instead

Tags: qiskit, support-vector-compat

i was trying to train SVC on same features i used to train VQC, but i am getting the error ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (100, 2) instead. when i try to fit SVC but this features works for VQC, why. can some expalain why it fits to VQC and not SVC and how can i fit to SVC to so i could compare both SVC and VQC performance on these featurues.

The train test features are made from ad_hoc_data imported from qiskit machine learning datasets library.
from qiskit_machine_learning.datasets import ad_hoc_data
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = ad_hoc_data(50, 20, 2, 0.1)

code for VQC:
[[code SVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slMZU.png)]
[Code for VQC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Sum.png)

this code throws the value error:ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (100, 2) instead.

I was expecting the score from SVC code bugt instead getting valuerror.
when the features work on VQC why doesnt they work on SVC?